# WSL2 ,Ubuntu DNS problem , can not resolve host

Tags: macos, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

Hey i am quiet devastated at this point spent my whole day to setup that ubuntu still nothing.
I downloaded ubuntu 20.04 everything is set up but it just can not connect to nothing, like i can not even get updated it just fails to connect.

I TRIED literally everything i changed the `etc/resolv.conf` to nameserver 8.8.8.8 , i changed my local  internet protocol, and still nothing like what am i  supposed to do? Why its not working?

All the terminal does is  " could not resolve host " or "just failed to connect" i uninstalled multiple times , i had 18.04 before , got rid of that now 20.04 not working at all,  i just want to develop my ruby application on that but nothing seems to work.